# insert database table into another database table specific Column? WPF

Tags: c#, mysql, database, wpf

I'm really new to C#/WPF.

I try to program my first app. So I added a local database and create two tables (MangersTable, meetingsTable ).Now i want to let the meetingsTable is a column of the MangersTable.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].